# Discord JS stop collector when ephemeral message is dismissed

Tags: discord.js

I have a message component collector that waits for an input from a MessageButton within an interaction reply, but the message is ephemeral so if the message is dismissed the collector stays open, despite there being no buttons for the user to press.

```
const abConfirmRow = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
.addComponents([
  new Discord.MessageButton()
    .setCustomId(abConfirmID)
    .setLabel('Yes')
    .setStyle('SUCCESS'),
  new Discord.MessageButton()
    .setCustomId(abCancelID)
    .setLabel('No')
    .setStyle('DANGER'),
]);

await interaction.reply({ content: confirmMessage, embeds: [{
  description: msgEmbed.description,
  image: msgEmbed.image,
}], components: [abConfirmRow], ephemeral: true });

const filter = button => (button.customId === abConfirmID || button.customId === abCancelID) && button.user.id === interaction.member.id;
const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 30000 });
```

I have looked through the documentation and on various sites and can't seem to find any sort of "on dismissed" event listener.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the collector will still timeout if the user dismisses the message/interaction. One thing that may help (as I am struggling with this exact problem), is to use `idle` instead of `time`. `time` is absolute; starting at the beginning of the interaction, regardless of how much time is spent with each interaction. `idle`, however is interaction to interaction.

So, my workaround for this is to set `idle` to 10-15 seconds (or whatever suits you). At least then, the collector will time out faster than waiting for the full `time` to run out. It's not ideal, some kind of event on dismissal would be nice, but it is workable. I don't use `time` at all.

For example:

`const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, idle: 10000 });`

Then, just catch the `idle` reason in the `end` event:

```
collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'complete') {                
        // ...
    } else if (reason === 'idle') {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Hope this helps until we can find a better answer.